# Silverlight - Stop Query completed event after executing once

Tags: silverlight

I have a foreach loop which is below:

```
 foreach (var rec in lstPRSCRPT)
          {
              var OrderItemQuery = GV.dbContext.Load(GV.dbContext.GetOrdritemsQuery (rec.PresNo));
              OrderItemQuery.Completed += new EventHandler(OrderItemQuery_Completed);              
          }
```

In the OrderItemQuery_Completed event, for each call back, I have some calculations to find if certian condition is reached. If so, I dont want to get any further OrderItemQuery_Completed call back. Is there a way I can do that? Is there any way to stop the OrderItemQuery_Completed from being fired.

I unscubscirbed the event and I get an eror as shown in pic:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can unsubscribe from this event in the handler like this:

```
private void OrderItemQuery_Completed(object sender, ...) 
{
    var query = (OrderItemsQuery)sender;
    query.Completed -= OrderItemQuery_Completed;
    ....
}
```

Comment: @sony - Replace it with the type of `OrderItemQuery` variable in your code, i.e. this underscored thing must be the name of the type of query object (which has the `Completed` event).

Comment: something like aType = OrderItemQuery.GetType();    var query = (aType)sender; 
          query.Completed -= OrderItemQuery_Completed;

Comment: @sony - No, just replace the underlined type name with the actual **name** of the type of the query object.

Comment: sorry I dont understand, How will I get the name of it? thanks

Comment: @sony - Just hover the mouse over `var` keyword before the `OrderItemQuery` variable in the code that you posted in your question. In the tooltip you will see the name of the type. Or see what type that is returned from the `GV.dbContext.Load` method. Copy the type name and past it place of `OrderItemsQuery`.